# Print characters in collation order

Tags: bash

Given for example the class of "visible characters"

```
[:graph:]
```

AKA

```
[\x21-\x7E]
```

How could I go about printing those in "collation" order, that is the order determined by `LC_COLLATE`

Comment: `[:graph:]` includes non-ASCII characters in locales like `en_US.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run it through sort. The hardest part is getting a list of characters. This works for ASCII:

```
for ((i=0x21; i<=0x7E; i++))
do 
    printf "\\$(printf '%03o' $i)\0"; 
done | sort -z | tr -d '\0'
```

It writes out each character followed by a NUL byte, then sorts them all (`sort` considers LC_COLLATE), and finally deletes the NULs.